# Difference between "${param[0]}" and ${1} in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ifs

I'm looking at some old scripts and I found some parameter assignment that I have not seen before. A while loop reads from a text file and passes the values to a function. The items in the text file look like this:

```
user_one:abcdef:secretfolder
```

the first stage of the function then looks like this:

```
 IFS=':' read -a param <<< $@

 user="${param[0]}"
 pass="${param[1]}"
 user_folders="${param[2]}"
```

I have not seen this sort of assignment before and was wondering if this is just an alternative way of handling it. Is the above the same as this?

```
IFS=':' read -a param <<< $@

user="${1}"
pass="${2}"
user_folders="${3}"
```

(change in values to 1-3 due to `${0}` being the name of the file itself). This script is 5 years old; This original sort of assignment just seems a longer way to to it, unless I've missed something

I'm still learning shell scripting but as I understand, setting `IFS=':'` will split the fields on `:` rather than whitespace and so in the examples, the value of `"${param[0]}"` and `${1}` passed to the function would be `user_one`

Can someone please explain if there is a reason why `"${param[0]}"` should be used instead of `${1}`?

Comment: `IFS=':' read -a param <<< $@` is creepy!! Unless the author wants to remove all `\ ` from `$@`, trim all leading & ending spaces, convert all space+ to single space and mix up the arguments of the function, then the correct command would be `IFS=':' read -ra param <<< "$1"`

Comment: there are multiple lines on the file that is being read if that wasn't obvious. So there are about 10 users each on a new line. So would $@ be ok to use in this case as it will take in all the users?

Comment: @scrow you may want to show a minmal example: few sample lines from the file (making sure to include a line that includes a few users on the same line), the `while` loop (reading from the file), and the actual function call; processing a line like `a:b:c` is going to be different from processing a line like `a:b:c g:h:i m:n:o x:y:z`; also note that `func_call a:b:c` is processed differently from `IFS=: func_call a:b:c` ... point being that it may help to see a bit more of the data and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```sh
IFS=':' read -a param <<< $@
```

reads the `:`-separated fields from the command arguments (`$@`) into the array variable named `param`. Bash arrays work just like lists in other languages, and you index them with brackets. `${param[0]}` is the first field, `${param[1]}` then next, and so on. Arrays like this can contain *anything*, and it's just because of the `$@` in the `read` command that this `param` array happens to contain the arguments. It could just as easily contain `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` if it were created like:

```sh
param=(foo bar baz)
```

The `${1}`, `${2}` etc. syntax **always** refers to the script arguments though.